# compile error with facebook and parse sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I am having the following compile error with Parse SDK 1.7.5 and facebook SDK 4.3.0

> "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
>
> "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
>
> "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
>
> "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Here is the my Application delegate:

```
import UIKit
import Bolts
import Parse

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    // Initialize Parse.
    Parse.setApplicationId("Lqy9Q5hchqnXNVY56hnyTwabrij4R2FDP47FsLZ3",
        clientKey: "h1BXeaoBgytENrnNfxok1ghlTWiEadM5vX5K4bqU")

    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    // [Optional] Track statistics around application opens.
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    let userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationType.Alert |  UIUserNotificationType.Badge |  UIUserNotificationType.Sound);

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current Installation and save it to Parse
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}



}
```

There is no error until I added PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions) in the code.

> More detailed error infor:  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>         -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
>   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o) ld: symbol(s) not
>   found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Check what library and frameworks needed for these SDKs and include in your project.

Comment: I am pretty sure all the frameworks needed are included

Comment: Have you added necessary other linker flags ? e.g., `-ObjC` ? and (non)recursive path of any external library ? Also, can you please check if this Parse SDK is compatible with the facebook SDK you are using ?

Comment: I tried to add -ObjC to the linker flag, it generated more error

Comment: I solved the problem by remove ParseFacebookUtils in the link library and only keep ParseFacebookUtilsV4